# transferred Magento website to live server , why does it show 404 error?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have transferred Magento website to live server successfully but, after 5 days i am not able to use any link . not even admin.

my website loads perfectly fine :

www. example.com

But when i click on links or my admin link I see this weird thing in my url :

http://www.example.com/%7B%7Bwww.example.com%7D%7D/?SID=bcsgcudcnkj54nhknxsncnks23cabout-magento-demo-store/

the url contains the domain name twice , with flower brackets, which re-directs to 404 error.

Kindly help.

Comment: refresh your cache and review your  .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

If you have cleared your cache, this normally means you have a configuration error in your domain name.   Based on your links, I am going to assume your settings have '{{www.yourdomain.com}}' instead of 'http://www.yourdomain.com'.

Look into your database in the table core_config_data for an entry with the paths web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url and make sure they have the 'http://' prefix.